# While opening Oracle From Excel, it shows the error "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc, jdbc-odbc, instantclient

While Opening instantclient_12_1 in Windows 7, from Excel  it shows the following error.

> "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the
>   Driver and Application"

I will provide the Image of the error after we select the TNS from excel Data Connection
[image]

Also When I try to Configure agin the Configure file it showing Another Error

[image]

Comment: Most likely you have 32 bit Excel and 64 bit Oracle driver or 64 bit Excel and 32 bit Oracle driver

Comment: Thanks. sir, it is the issue of the bit 32 and 64, am using 64 bit so i reinstall the office and i got the solution.